# Rails 5 API + MySQL Bigint Primary Key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, bigint

Do you know if they have fixed old problem about having primary key as `bigint` in rails 5?

Could you please help me how to deal with that?